# What is the distribution of the risk-free asset?

Tags: probability, distribution, risk-free

If the risk-free asset has a volatility of $0$, therefore making its mean equal to the risk-free rate, $r_f$, does this mean that it has no probability distribution, and therefore there is no reason to model it parametrically (i.e. with $\mathcal{N}(\cdot)$ or other)?

How does this situation change when we drop the usual assumption of a constant $r_f$, since, empirically, central banks actually make it time-varying?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard way to think about this is that at time $t$ the riskless asset gives you known return of $r_{f,t}$ over a short time period. However, this rate may itself be time-varying and stochastic so that we don't know its futures values, say $r_{f,t+s}$. E .g. a common assumption is that the rate follows an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process (implying that the conditional distribution is normal).

In case you assume that $r_{f,t}$ is actually constant, say $c$, it still has a probability distribution. Here you need to define $r_{f,t}$ as a random variable that takes the value $c$ for all outcomes of the sample space. Naturally the distribution of $r_{f,t}$ is then such that all the probability mass lies at this single point: $P(r_{f,t}=c)=1$.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the previous answer, one example of such asset (returning 'risk-free rate') is a money market (or bank) account, but it is only ****locally*** risk-free*, with value accruing continuously at the risk-free rate prevailing in the market at every instant. It is *risk-free only over a short period of time*. In long term it is stochastic too. Its SDE is:

$$ dB_t =r_t  B_t \; dt, \; B_0 =1, $$
or, equivalently,
$$ B_t = \exp \left( \int_0^t r_u\; du \right), $$

where $r_t$ is a *stochastic* [progressively measurable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressively_measurable_process) process with locally integrable paths, making $B_t$ a [*finite variation*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/291241/why-are-these-function-of-finite-variation) process with [*null quadratic variation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#:%7E:text=A%20process%20X%20is%20said,variation%20processes%2C%20and%20is%20zero.). Intuitively, this means that it has a smaller degree of randomness with respect to the other risky assets. (In FX or equity option pricing, based on such intuition, one even assumes time-dependent *deterministic* interest rate.)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is a useful question. I'd like to add an illustrative example to the excellent answers above, if not for the OP then for others.

A tractable (albeit unrealistic) model for the short rate is the following
$$
dr(t) = \sigma dW(t), \quad r(0) = 0
$$
where $W$ is a standard Brownian motion.

So,
\begin{align}
E[r(t)] &= 0\\
Var[r(t)] &= \sigma^2 t
\end{align}

Now, the risk-free asset (the money market account) is
$$
\log B(t)/B(0) = \int_0^t r(u) du
$$
So we can speak of the expectation of $\log B(t)/B(0)$, which is given by
$$
E \left[\log B(t)/B(0)\right] = 0
$$
and also
$$
Var \left[\log B(t)/B(0)\right] = \frac{\sigma^2}{3}t^3
$$

So, as said by ir7, it's locally risk-free but not 'globally' risk free.